# msSQL jdbc .. I connected to the server but how to connect to use a specific databaseName

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

Last time I used SQL with Java/Eclipse I had a SQL script linked to the Project.

This time, I connected to a different server using jdbc format (not localhost) and it connects correctly.

Now I need to get into this specific database named WInfo but I don't know how to do that.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://serverName:1433/;user=UserName;password=******;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below connection string:

```
 c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME:PORTNO;databaseName=DATABASENAME;
 user=MyUserName;password=*****");
```

OR

```
 c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME:PORTNO;databaseName=DATABASENAME",
 MyUserName, MyPassword);
```